# Can I partial a Java method invocation in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a method on an object.

```
myObject.myMethod(1)
```

I can invoke this in Clojure

```
(.myMethod myObject 1)
```

I can also invoke it using information from the lexical environment

```
(let [x 1] (.myMethod myObject x))
```

Can I do this with a partial? E.g.

```
(let [myPartial (partial .myMethod myObject)]
      (myPartial 1))
```

This gives me a

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: .myMethod in this context

I'm currently making this work with an anonymous function

```
(let [myThing #(.myMethod myObject %)]
      (myThing 1))
```

But if it would be nice to use a partial in this case. Is it possible?

I'm sure the answer will be to do with binding and dispatch but I don't yet have a feeling for where during the compiling and execution the dispatch happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have partial in your case, use ([memfn](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn)).

```
(memfn myMethod args)
```

In the REPL:

```
user=> (doc memfn)
-------------------------
clojure.core/memfn
([name & args])
Macro
Expands into code that creates a fn that expects to be passed an
object and any args and calls the named instance method on the
object passing the args. Use when you want to treat a Java method as
a first-class fn. name may be type-hinted with the method receiver's
type in order to avoid reflective calls.
```